# How to Replace Every Space in a Notepad++ Doc With a Null Character?

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

I copy and pasted the hex (I think it's hex, but I have no clue) from one document to another and all the null characters turned into spaces. How would I change them all back to null characters, preferably by using Ctrl+H?

Comment: Are you sure they changed to spaces? Maybe they are simply displayed as spaces?

Comment: Likely it was a text conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there may not be a simple way to do this in Notepad++. Even using the Hex plugin, bulk replacement seemed to cause Notepad++ to hang in testing. Individual manual replacement is an option (the simplest being with the Hex plugin just mentioned), but for a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> style "all in one shot", you may want to try a Trial copy of [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/) or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your text to a hex string under Extensions -> Converter and then search and replace 20 with 00 and convert everything back. Only problem would be that this would also replace e.g. "1208", being the two bytes 0x12 and 0x08.
In this form you can use a regex search an replace and search for `20(?=(?:[\da-fA-F]{2})+$|$)` (courtesy of [stribizhev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31147478/regex-that-only-matches-on-odd-even-indices)) and replace it with 00.
Then just convert it back and you're done.